# Query room sqlite checking two columns

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components

I have a conversation table like so

**Conversation**

```
+----+-----------+--------------+
| Id | sender_id | recipient_id |
+----+-----------+--------------+
|  0 |         3 |            2 |
|  1 |         2 |            1 |
|  2 |         1 |            3 |
+----+-----------+--------------+
```

So basically, a sender_id could be in the recipient_id column depending on anyone that initiates a conversation first.

How do I make a query, for instance passing a recipient_id, 2. And check if it is in sender_id column, or recipient_id column. Something like:

```
@Query("select * from conversation where sender_id = :userId OR recipient_id = :userId  ")
LiveData<Conversation> getAConversationByUserId(long userId);
```

Will this work? Haven't tried it. should I use `|| or OR`?

Comment: why not try ? Are you afraid of breaking the internet ?

...and yes, it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try the following:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM conversation
    WHERE sender_id = user_id OR recipient_id = user_id;
```

it's the same as you asked but I've laid it out this way as I use workbench. I've used OR in the statement.

As pointed out in the comments, in SQLlite || is specifically a concatenation operator and does not operate the same as OR. Apologies for my previous error!

Comment: I ran the exact same statement in workbench using || to test this before I gave my answer, and it gave the exact same result!

Comment: Read my response. I specified that I tested this specifically in workbench NOT in sql lite. I know there are differences across different types of SQL which is why I specified what I did and where I tested it.

Comment: And the answer I gave worked considering I used OR not ||, however my statement about || being the same in SQL lite is wrong. I've now corrected that!